# Reverse for 'uutiset' not found. 'uutiset' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

I'm trying update django project from django1.4/python2.7 to django2.2/python3.7. Now I'm confused with the traceback after python manage.py runserver (and after going to page /uutiset/):

```
Internal Server Error: /uutiset/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\osakeekstra\extranet\views.py", line 190, in uutiset
    return render(request, 'hello.html')
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\miettinj\verkko\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 660, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'uutiset' not found. 'uutiset' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[03/Nov/2021 14:21:17] "GET /uutiset/ HTTP/1.1" 500 132139
```

see the urls.py, views.py, hello.html and INSTALLED_APPS below.

The problem must be in hello.html. If I remove this line

```
<p><a href="{% url 'extranet:uutiset' %}">Uutiset</a></p>
```

from it I get Hello word in my browser page at url /uutiset/, which means that urls.py should be correct, but the html doesn't undrstand 'extranet:uutiset' as a view function. It was created as ordinary django app using command 'python manage.py startapp'.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from extranet.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^uutiset/', uutiset),
     ]
```

extranet/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render        
@login_required    
def uutiset(request):
    return render(request, 'hello.html')
```

hello.html:

```
   <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
       <h1>Hello World<h1>
       <p><a href="{% url 'extranet:uutiset' %}">Uutiset</a></p>
     </body>
    </html>
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',    
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'django.contrib.admin',  
    #'extranet.apps.ExtranetConfig',
    'extranet',      
)
```

Comment: can you try like this? url(r'^uutiset/', uutiset, name='uutiset')

Comment: @EkiSaputra Thanks, it works, but how can I make also this line url(r'^sv/uutiset/', uutiset_sv, name='uutiset_sv'), work ? Seems that that the regex has to be renamed to 'uutiset_sv', which doesn't make sense...

Comment: yes of course work, url namespaces allow you to uniquely reverse named URL patterns even if different applications use the same URL names, you can read this on the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

Comment: sorry i give you wrong version documentation of django, this for django 2.2 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your URL pattern like this

```
url(r'^uutiset/', uutiset, name='uutiset')
```

because reverse need naming URL patterns, you can read this on the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns